# Pycharm Intellisense not working for some libraries?

Tags: python, scipy, pycharm, networkx, intellisense

I'm using NetworkX for a project, but Pycharm does not display class methods for Graphs.
How can I fix this?

Bellow is the current behavior I'm getting. Intellisense displays when I use nx.Graph(), but does not display for the actual graph G.

[image]

[image]

Comment: There can be several reasons for this, most of the times you've installed the library and it's a compiled version written in C that can't be introspected. What you need to find in those cases are the stub files of the library and install them (they are frequently included, but sometimes not). I haven't used networkx so I don't know but these are just the usual reasons... This is just an educated guess but if it's right it might point you -or any prospective contributor- in the right direction.

Comment: `networkx` is purely python, you can even check that method: https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/_modules/networkx/convert_matrix.html#from_scipy_sparse_matrix.

Comment: The graph constructors in networkx can return different classes, depending on the value of the `create_using` variable. Your IDE would need to evaluate the code to know what object you are creating but it obviously is not doing that (nor should it, that would be a terrible idea).

Comment: @Moose I think you should ask PaulBroderson and Sparky05 to convert their comments into answers and that you'll accept and upvote them. :D